# How to get the time at which a request is made from the request object in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to log the time at which a request is made. How can I get that info from a request object in rails 3?

Comment: What is your intent? If the current time won't work and microseconds matter, this is a very peculiar use case for which the exact intent has significant implications on what you use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create your Rack middleware, which will add a timestamp to request.
For instance (haven't checked it, but it gives you the idea):

```
module Middleware
  class Timestamp
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      env[:timestamp] = Time.now
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

And add it in application.rb (config.middleware.use)

Comment: Thank you. This did give me an idea of how to do it. But it is sufficient if I just set a timestamp in a controller in my app.

Comment: Adding it in controller might not be ideal since the request could have been initiated few seconds eariler than  it hit a controller. I would try adding timestamp in the client if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The request.env does not seem to include a timestamp:

```
<% for item in request.env %>
  <%= item %><br />
<% end %>
```

And I don't see anything related here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Is it sufficient for your application to just set a timestamp in your controller in a before_filter?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But, is setting and getting the timestamp from the controller the only way? There should be some way to know when the request object is created, right?

Comment: The honest answer is that I don't know. I was interested in your question and therefore checked request.env and the API docs and did not find anything.